# How can I do two columns in bootstrap select

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want two columns in a bootstrap select. Like this

[image: illustrated image]

How can I do?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: What is problem in this question? Why negative voting?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use two columns with [**`bootstrap-select`**](https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select/). But it has some limitations. The trick is to use `flex` with `flex-direction: columns` to define the columns and use the `.divide` class (which is generated when using `optgroup`) to set a new line.

> ***Note** flex columns needs a fixed height to work correctly, so you need an idea how many elements are in each column.*

[image: screenshot]

```js
$('.form-select-vidconvert').selectpicker();
```

```css
.row {
    padding: 8px 20px;
    min-height: 200px
}

.form-select-vidconvert {
    border-radius: 18px;
}


.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu {
    height: 160px !important;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu.open > .dropdown-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%; /* has to be set for the divider to work */
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu.open > .dropdown-menu li {
    flex-grow: 0;                
    width: 50%;
}

.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu.open > .dropdown-menu li.divider {
    //outline: 1px dotted red; /* debug */
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 0;
    height: unset;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.12.4/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.12.4/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<select class="form-control form-select-vidconvert" title="Multiselect example with two columns">
  
  <optgroup label="Category 1">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>

  <optgroup label="Category 2">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
  </optgroup>

</select>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-xs-6">option1</label>
<label class="col-xs-6">option2</label>
</div>
</div>
```

this sets the small device like phone to 2 columns 
depending on the size of device changing the "xs" to "sm"  or "md" or "lg" depending on the size screen